# How to plot the count of anomalies grouped by the factory and component?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code using `countplot` to plot the count of anomalies grouped by the factory:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(x='factory', hue='anomaly', data=train_df)
```

This is working (with a very small image width however), but I need to plot a chart that shows the count of products grouped by factory and anomaly.

How can I do this?

The chart can be very large as there are dozens of anomalies and components, so probably I'll have to generate a larger image. What do you suggest?

Here's a small sample of the data:

```
product_id,factory,anomaly,component
1,1,AC1,W2
2,3,AB1,J1
3,2,AC3,L3
4,4,BA2,T2
5,3,BA2,T2
6,1,AA1,X2
7,4,AC2,J1
8,2,CA1,N1
9,2,AB3,J1
10,4,BB3,W1
11,2,AC3,C3
12,4,CA1,M1
13,3,BC3,Q1
14,2,AC2,O3
```

And here's the url to the complete: [CSV](https://gist.github.com/julianonunes/47794838fb841c659c2a7ac4b7e33a50)

How the plot should look like:

[image: Excel plot]

Comment: What is your input data? What would you like your plot to look like? Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest just added the sample data and the plot generated on Excel as a format example. For each row (product_id) I have to group by the factory and the anomaly, and then count the number of products of each group.

Comment: What do blue and orange stand for here?

Comment: Previously I haven't been able to get the plot I want on Excel, but now I think it is ok. Each column represents a factory, then these columns repeat for each anomaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you would want to create a countplot like

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(x='anomaly', hue='factory', data=df)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

[image]

You could also create a pivot table of the factories and anomalies with the number of different components as values.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data/component_factory.txt")

piv = df.pivot_table(values='component', index='anomaly', columns='factory', 
                         aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()))

piv.plot.bar(width=0.8)

plt.show()
```

[image]